# How to access django database with pytest

Tags: django, pytest

I am wanting to use pytest with django to test api queries. Is there any way to do this in pytest without resorting to creating a test database? Pytest keeps throwing an error that database access is not allowed. I end up having to do this at the top of my pytest files:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","MyProject.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

I tried using the pytest-django library, but it doesn't have a mark for accessing the db that I can use.

Comment: Can you add the test case throwing that error? `pytest` can run tests that extend `django.test.TestCase` just fine. If you want to write test cases as functions, you need to use `pytest-django`. You can access the db in fixtures that depend on the `db` fixture and in tests that are marked with `@pytest.mark.django_db`.

Comment: Please give a _Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example_ https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to rtfd:
https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html

> pytest-django takes a conservative approach to enabling database access. By default your tests will fail if they try to access the database. Only if you explicitly request database access will this be allowed. This encourages you to keep database-needing tests to a minimum which makes it very clear what code uses the database.